# Passing additional parameters to the callback of fs.readFile in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Is it possible to pass additional parameters to the callback function of a `fs.readFile`. I have my code to read a directory and parse all the XML documents. I need to pass the filename down the callback chain for additional processing. As of now my code is

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports.extractXMLBody = function (dirPath, ext) {
    fs.stat(dirPath, function (err, stats) {
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            fetchFiles(dirPath, ext, function (listOfFiles) {
                _.each(listOfFiles, function (val, key) {
                    var completePath = dirPath + '/' + val;
                    var fileName = path.basename(val, path.extname(val))
                    // TODO : Figure out to pass additional parameters
                    fs.readFile(fullPath, parseXML);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here `parseXML` is the callback i have defined as a separate function & I want to pass the variable `newFileName` to the callback function `parseXML`.

Note : If i write the callback as anonymous function, i can pass the access the variable but I'm trying to avoid the further nesting of callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't have additional values passed to the callback function since that is not supported by `fs.readFile()`. It will only pass back 2 values to the callback function at all times. It follows an [error-first callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) structure, so that means the first parameter will be an `Error` or null if one didn't occur and the next argument will contain the data of the file, if there is any.

If you want to access the `fileName` variable inside your callback for `fs.readFile()` then you would need to define it within the same scope where `fs.readFile()` is called. This would more or less require you to go with an anonymous function. However you should still name it for better Error StackTraces.

```
_.each(listOfFiles, function (val, key) {
  var completePath = dirPath + '/' + val;
  var fileName = path.basename(val, path.extname(val));

  fs.readFile(fullPath, function parseXML(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      // parseXML and still have access to fileName
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: that's bad news for me. Leaves me no choice but to go with anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a way for you to do it now. You can use the `.bind` function to pass down a variable to your callback function.
Eg:

```
    for (file of files) {
      fs.readFile(`./${file}`, 'utf8', gotFile.bind({ "filename": file }))
}
```

And in your callback function (`gotFile` in my example), you van use the variable filename as such:

```
console.log(`Read ${this.file}.json`)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Aditya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12505789/aditya) commented, `.bind()` solves the problem but the provided code didn't work for me so I got it to work like this:

```
fs.readFile(fullPath, parseXML.bind(null, additionalParameter))
```

```
const parseXML = (additionalParameter, error, fileContents) => {
  console.log(additionalParameter)
}
```